# Modify Apache Shindig to accept new Data Pipelines

Tags: java, javascript, opensocial, apache-shindig

I've been working on integrating [Open Social](http://www.opensocial.org/) into a service, and modifying [Apache Shindig](http://shindig.apache.org/) to accommodate. There are some non-open-social features I'd like to use, and I've figured out so far how to add basic js features and server-side data methods. However, I'd like to add to the [Data Pipelining](http://wiki.opensocial.org/index.php?title=OpenSocial_Templates_Developer's_Guide) standard, and I'm having a hard time finding documentation. Does anyone have any idea how to make changes to the Open Social Templates portion of Apache Shindig? The documentation is, uh, sparse.

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of changes that you woul dlike to make to the template? The docs do not look too sparse.

Comment: @Vincent. I have an custom SPI hooked in, and I'd like to know how I could add new tags for it to accept in the data pipelining feature. For example, if my custom spi has a `getInfo` method, how could I hook that up to a DataPipeline and enable gadgets to access the data with that API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have too much experience working with Shindig, hovewer i will try to help.

Apache Shindig uses [Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) as dependency injection framework which makes it simple to overwrite shindig service implementations. With google guice, you can build your own modules and inject them into shindig.

Probably, you need to extend `org.apache.shindig.gadgets.render.ProxyRenderer`, implement `org.netmera.portal.shindig.RequestPipeline`, `org.apache.shindig.gadgets.templates.TemplateModule` and more and more...

I think, to hook your service, a module like this is needed.
Here, **MyHandler.class** is my own handler:

```
/**
 * Provides social api component injection.
 */
public class MySocialApiModule extends SocialApiGuiceModule {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.apache.shindig.social.core.config.SocialApiGuiceModule#configure()
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(){
        this.bind(ParameterFetcher.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("DataServiceServlet")).to(DataServiceServletFetcher.class);
        this.bind(Boolean.class).annotatedWith(Names.named(AnonymousAuthenticationHandler.ALLOW_UNAUTHENTICATED)).toInstance(Boolean.TRUE);
        this.bind(XStreamConfiguration.class).to(XStream081Configuration.class);
        this.bind(BeanConverter.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("shindig.bean.converter.xml")).to(BeanXStreamConverter.class);
        this.bind(BeanConverter.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("shindig.bean.converter.json")).to(BeanJsonConverter.class);
        this.bind(BeanConverter.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("shindig.bean.converter.atom")).to(BeanXStreamAtomConverter.class);
        this.bind(new TypeLiteral<List<AuthenticationHandler>>(){}).toProvider(AuthenticationHandlerProvider.class);
        final Multibinder<Object> handlerBinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(this.binder(), Object.class, Names.named("org.apache.shindig.handlers"));
        for (final Class handler : this.getHandlers()) {
            handlerBinder.addBinding().toInstance(handler);
        }
        this.bind(OAuthDataStore.class).to(MyOAuthDataStore.class);
    }

    /**
     * Hook to provide a Set of request handlers. Subclasses may override to add
     * or replace additional handlers.
     */
    @Override
    protected Set<Class<?>> getHandlers(){
        return ImmutableSet.<Class<?>> of(ActivityHandler.class, AppDataHandler.class, MyPersonHandler.class, MessageHandler.class, MyHandler.class, ACLHandler.class);
    }
}
```

Hovewer, you should dig in **Shindig** and Guice to make things as exactly what you want. There are quite a bit examples on web that explains extending and configuring Shindig with Guice.